# Colspan not working correctly in html5 table

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble aligning my first row with colspan, it doesn't correctly colspan. This is the result:

[image]

```css
    .header-wrap {
      display: flex;                  
      align-items: flex-start;        
      justify-content: space-between; 
    }
    
    .header-blue   { margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: #3498DB; color: #fff; }
    .header-left   { width: 400px; text-align: left; }
    .header-left > h3 {margin: 5px 0 !important;}
    .header-right  { width: 400px; text-align: right; }
    .header-center { width: 400px; text-align: center; }
```

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered box-shadow--6dp">
      <tr class="header-blue">
        <td colspan="4" class="header-wrap">
          <div class="header-left"><h3>{{ recom.name }}</h3></div>
          <div class="header-center"><b>note:</b> {{ recom.note | displayEmpty }}</div>
          <div class="header-right"><b>Date:</b> {{ recom.date }}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td scope="head">UREA/Organic Manure</td>
        <td scope="head">DAP</td>
        <td scope="head">MOP</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

---

but when I try to uncomment this below code, the colspan works but the aligning is broken.

```
.header-wrap {
/*  display: flex;                  
  align-items: flex-start;        
  justify-content: space-between; */
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add div under colspan td and that div give header-wrap class

[image]

Comment: Please see [answer]. Code should not be presented as an image.

Answer (score 7):

Clearly the `display: flex` is the culprit here.
You see if you style the `<td>` with `display:flex` is actually replacing the default display value:  `display: table-cell` 
Therefore the `<td>` will not be treated as a table cell element.

Solution: put another element inside the `<td>` and make it's display as flex.